# Stream chain wrapping done in the right way

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I'm using Bouncy Castle cryptographic API for C# to create armored output of encrypted data.

The code looks ugly, in particular, like this:

```
string result = string.Empty;

using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var armoredStream = AddArmorWrappingTo(outputStream))
    {
        using (var encryptedStream = AddEncryptionWrappingTo(armoredStream))
        {
            using (var literalStream = AddLiteralWrappingTo(encryptedStream))
            {
                using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
                {
                    this.Write(inputStream, literalStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outputStream.ToArray());
}

return result;
```

The issue here is if I will need to add compression of the data, I cannot change this piece of code, I need to write new one instead, since compressing in Bouncy Castle's world done as one more stream wrapper around future output stream.

To work properly, the streams need to be wrapped in correct order, and closed properly, otherwise there will be no usable result of this operation.

In addition all these intermediate streams should also present (I cannot overwrite the same stream variable over and over).

I've created extension methods to stream wrapper creators, and it looks like this now:

```
string result = string.Empty;

Stream[] pack = new Stream[3];

var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
var inputStream = new MemoryStream(input);

pack[0] = outputStream.Armor();
pack[1] = pack[0].EncryptWith(PublicKey);
pack[2] = pack[1].SplitByLiterals();

this.Write(inputStream, pack[2]);

pack[2].Close();
pack[1].Close();
pack[0].Close();

result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outputStream.ToArray());

return result;
```

I would say, the code become even worse.

My question is, is it possible to optimize stream wrapping? Maybe create array of delegates to wrap streams one by one and close them afterwards?

What's your experience on such tasks, is it possible to make this code more maintainable? Since currently adding compressing, or signing or excluding armoring is pain...

Comment: I'm a little confused by your "I cannot overwrite the same stream variable over and over" comment - what's the reason for that? Usually, if you wrap one stream in another, it's assumed that the outer stream will do whatever it likes with the inner stream and you shouldn't touch it yourself afterwards.

Comment: I was thinking to use single stream instead of `armoredStream`, `encryptedStream` and `literalStream`. But it didn't worked obviously.